# How to calculate free fermion ground state energy with zero temperature green's function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

We can use $Galitskii-Migdal$ formula:$$E=-\frac{1}{2}i\frac{V}{(2\pi)^4} \lim\limits_{\nu \to 0^+ } \int d^3k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega e^{i\omega \nu} (\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}+\hbar\omega)\,tr\,G(\mathbf{k},\omega)$$
for free fermion case:$$G^0_{\alpha\beta}(\mathbf{k},\omega)=\delta_{\alpha\beta}[\frac{\theta(k-k_F)}{\omega-\omega_k+i\eta}+\frac{\theta(k_F-k)}{\omega-\omega_k-i\eta}]$$
and $\omega_k=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}$, the indices $\alpha,\beta$ label spin, $\nu=t'-t$, $\nu\gt0$, $k_F$ is fermi wave vector.

Firstly, integrate out $\omega$,$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \, e^{i\omega\nu}(\omega_k+\omega)[\frac{\theta(k-k_F)}{\omega-\omega_k+i\eta}+\frac{\theta(k_F-k)}{\omega-\omega_k-i\eta}]\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega \,e^{i\omega\nu}[\theta(k-k_F)(1+\frac{2\omega_k-i\eta}{\omega-\omega_k+i\eta})+\theta(k_F-k)(1+\frac{2\omega_k+i\eta}{\omega-\omega_k-i\eta})]$$
so there are 2 delta functions, and the remained  2 terms can be calculated by residue theorem, set aside these 2 delta functions for the moment, the above integral becomes(because $\nu\gt0$):
$$2\pi i\, \theta(k_F-k)\,(2\omega_k+i\eta)\,e^{i(\omega_k+i\eta)\nu}$$
now the ground state energy becomes:
$$E=-\frac{1}{2} i \frac{V}{(2\pi)^4}(2s+1) \hbar\, 2\pi i\,\lim\limits_{\nu \to 0^+ } e^{-\eta\nu}\int d^3k \, \theta(k_F-k) \,(2\omega_k+i\eta)e^{i\omega_k \nu}$$
may be I can set $\eta=0$, and integrate out polar angle and azimuth angle, then the integral becomes:
$$4\pi\, \int_0^{k_F}2\omega_k\,k^2\,e^{i\omega_k\nu}\,dk$$
let $t^2=\omega_k=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}$,
$$\int_0^{t_F} t^4 \cos{(t^2\nu)}dt\\=\frac{t_F^3\sin{(t_F^2\nu)}}{2\nu}+\frac{3t_F\cos{(t_F^2\nu)}}{4\nu^2}-\frac{3}{4\nu^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\nu^{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{t_F^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$$
and 
$$\int_0^{t_F} \,t^4\,\sin{(t^2\nu)}dt\\=-\frac{t_F^3\cos{(t_F^2\nu)}}{2\nu}+\frac{3t_F\sin{(t_F^2\nu)}}{4\nu^2}-\frac{3}{4\nu^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\nu^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\frac{t_F^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$

take the limit $\nu \to 0^+$, the divergent terms are canceled exactly, the ground state energy becomes:
$$E=-\frac{1}{2}i\frac{V}{(2\pi)^4}(2s+1)\,\hbar\,2\pi i\,*4\pi\,*2*(\frac{2m}{\hbar})^{3/2}*(\frac{t_F^5}{2}-\frac{3t_F^5}{8}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}\frac{t_F^5}{5})\\=\frac{V}{4\pi^2}(2s+1)(\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2}\,2*\frac{1}{5}(\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m})^{5/2}$$
but from statistical mechanics, we know the energy is $$E=V\,\frac{g}{4\pi^2}(\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2}\,\frac{2}{5}\,\mu^{5/2}$$
$\mu$ is the zero temperature chemical potential, $\mu=\frac{\hbar^2 k_F^2}{2m}$
they are the same.

!*******************!

But there are 2 delta functions .

problem: can I drop these delta functions?
$$\lim\limits_{\nu \to 0^+ }\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega\nu}(\theta(k-k_F)+\theta(k_F-k))\,d\omega$$
!*******************!

---

using the same strategy, I can obtain the correct $N$:
$$N=\int d^3x\langle \hat n(x)\rangle=-i\frac{V}{2\pi^4}\lim\limits_{\nu \to 0^+ }\int d^3k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega\, e^{i\omega\nu}\,tr\,G(\mathbf{k},\omega)$$

$$N=(2s+1)\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\lim\limits_{\nu \to 0^+ }e^{-\eta\nu}\int d^3 k\,\theta(k_F-k)e^{i\omega_k\nu}$$
and $$\int_0^{t_F} t^2\,\cos{(t^2\nu)}dt\\=\frac{t_{F}\,\sin{(t_F^2\nu)}}{2\nu}-\frac{1}{2\nu}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\nu^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \frac{t_F^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$

$$\int_0^{t_F} t^2 \sin{(t^2\nu)} dt\\=-\frac{t_F\,\cos{(t_F^2\nu)}}{2\nu}+\frac{1}{2\nu}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\nu^{2n}}{(2n)!} \frac{t_F^{4n+1}}{4n+1}$$

so, $$N=(2s+1)\frac{V}{4\pi^2}2\,(\frac{2m}{\hbar})^{3/2}*[\frac{t_F^3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{t_F^3}{3}]\\=(2s+1)\frac{V}{4\pi^2} (\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2} \frac{2}{3}\mu^{3/2}$$
from statistical mechanics $N=V\frac{g}{4\pi^2}(\frac{2m}{\hbar^2})^{3/2}\,\frac{2}{3}\mu^{3/2}$, so using the zero temperature free fermion green's function I can get the correct particle number.

ref. {quantum theory of many-particle systems} A.L.Fetter and J.D.Walecka

Comment: So what's the problem?As you've shown the method works for both the energy and particle number.

Comment: @Hosein  Jan  I have dropped the delta function.

Comment: You mean the theta functions?

Comment: Since, $\nu$ is a constant I don't see why anyone would begrudge you to bring the limits inside, after all the result is correct.